# US visa after UK drink driving offense

Tags: visas, usa, uk, criminal-records

My family have travelled to the US several times from the UK. My husband was banned from driving for 12 months (drink driving charge) in the UK, but it was over 2 years ago. Will this have a negative impact on our travelling? Also, what documentation would he need if he is allowed to go? Would he have to visit the US Embassy in person to apply?

Comment: Note that Canada takes past DUIs by visitors much more seriously, so if he wants to visit Canada from the USA, there will be much more paperwork involved: https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/inadmissibility.html.

Answer (score 6):

A drunk driving conviction **by itself** does not make your husband [inadmissible](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/USCIS/About%20Us/Electronic%20Reading%20Room/Customer%20Service%20Reference%20Guide/Inadmissibillity_and_Waivers.pdf). No need to go to US Embassy or special documentation.

The [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/) form asks applicants the following:

> Have you ever been arrested or convicted for a crime that resulted in
>   serious damage to property, or serious harm to another person or
>   government authority?

If the answer is no, he's fine to use ESTA, otherwise he needs to apply for a visa.

Comment: No direct experience with it, but "arrested" seems like a pretty low bar in some places where they tend arrest (or is it "detain") everyone involved, particularly foreigners, in case of an accident.

Comment: At least as regards the UK, it's necessary to distinguish between *arrest* and *detention*.  Though the latter power is more limited than some policemen like to believe, [it does exist in certain circumstances](https://iaingould.co.uk/2017/03/21/can-the-police-detain-you-without-arresting-you/), and doesn't constitute arrest.  However, that a government that claims to respect the presumption of innocence predicates decisions on the basis of police investigations that do not result in convictions is a hypocrisy which I fear it would be inappropriate to examine here.